# extract json in controller file angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

i'm using AngularJS and Ionic framework, and i have a Json object that i use normally on the html file with ng-repeat, like this:

```
 <ion-item ng-repeat="user in users">
                    {{user.alt1}}
                </ion-item>
```

But i want to select a object from "users" (pergunta) in my controller.js file and compare with the value that i have in $scope.alternativa.

```
  var num="3";

$http.get('http://localhost/prova/mostraquestao.php',{params:{"id":num}}).then(function(resp) {
$scope.users = resp.data; **$scope.correta = $scope.users.pergunta**  }, function(err) {
console.error('ERR', err);  });

 $scope.validaQuest = function(alt){
   $scope.alternativa = alt;
    if($scope.alternativa === $scope.correta){ 

       var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
   title: "Resposta Correta",
    template: alt
 }); 
    $scope.pontos += 1;

    }
}
```

**$scope.correta = $scope.users.pergunta** is the question, i cannot find a way to get the this value from users inside controller, like i get the value in html using ng-repeat.

Comment: Broken code isn't a good substitute for a proper explanation of what you want the code to do. Also we don't know what data looks like either. Add more details to question

Comment: Sorry , I added a little more information , but what I really want is to get a value from a table in my db and compare with a radio value sent by the user. A question validator.

Comment: try using `angular.equals()`

Comment: what did you don't able to do ?

Comment: The problem is in "$scope.users.pergunta", i cannot get any value from this. If i use  <ion-item ng-repeat="user in users"> {{user.pergunta}}              </ion-item> i get the value in html, but not in JS file.

Comment: Still not 100% clear what you are trying to do. Are you tring to get it by clicking in page or ??? Where is `validaQuest ()` called from?